# How to detect Mosaic virus infestation in Hippeastrum seedlings?

Tags: diseases, seedlings

If a seed was harvested from an infected Hippeastrum plant, it may happen that by handling the seed pod a virus was transferred to the seed while handling the mother plant and then touching the seed. The virus may remain viable in the germination medium and enter the seedling as soon as it begins to sprout.

Once a seedling is infected, how soon can I detect the infestation? Does it look the same as with adult plants? (patchy, fractal discoloration/variegation).